# Using jQuery, how can I store the result of a call to the $.ajax function, to be re-used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Thanks for reading this.

I imagine this is really a javascript question, and my title probably does not get at the heart of what I am trying to do, but I want to store the result of my ajax request in a global variable. This would allow me to test the var before making the ajax call...and avoid repeated ajax calls for the same data. I need to be able to pass the variable name from the click event down through the populateSelect function into the ajaxCall function.

It seems like I could pass a function as a parameter, but I have not been able to make that work.

I like to include working examples in my questions, but in this case the latency in the call to the server is part of the problem.

Thanks

```
$('#getSelectOptions').bind("click", function() {
 populateSelect(this);
});

function populateSelect(whatWasClicked) {
 var thisSelect = $(whatWasClicked).parents("div").find("select") ;

 var before = function() { $(loading).show() ;  } ;
 var complete = function() { $(loading).hide() ;  } ;
 var data = {'_service' : 'myService', '_program' : 'myProgram' } ;
 var error = function(){alert("Error"); } ;
 var success = function(request) { $(thisSelect).html(request) ; };
 var waitTime = 20000 ;

 ajaxCall(thisSelect, waitTime, before, complete, data, success, error ) ;
}

function ajaxCall(elementToPopulate, waitTime, whatToDoBeforeAjaxSend,
                  whatToDoAfterAjaxSend, dataToSendToTheServer, 
                  whatToDoAfterSuccess, whatToDoAfterError) {
 $.ajax({   
  type: "post", 
  url: "http://myURL/cgi-bin/broker",   
  dataType: "text", 
  data: dataToSendToTheServer, 
  timeout: waitTime, 
  beforeSend: whatToDoBeforeAjaxSend, 
  error: whatToDoAfterError(request),
  success: whatToDoAfterSuccess(request)
 });
}
```

**EDIT** Further education in how to write a good question... I should have mentioned that I call populateSelect to populate multiple selects..so I need way to reference the results for each select

Comment: Isnt it easier to simple check if the select is already populated?
And it is posible to pass functions as variables. You simply need to assign the function name ( without quotes or () ) to a variable, and you can execute it by simply doing variable().

Comment: you are right...that is a good way to avoid making repeat ajax calls...but I did want a method for storing the result (of the ajax call) for re-use. I couldn't get the function-as-a-variable method to store the ajax result..when I referenced the global var on the second call it was "undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has a $.data method which you can use to store/retrieve items related to any element on the page.

```
//e.g. create some object
var inst = {};
inst.name = 'My Name'

var target = $('#textbox1');

//save the data
$.data(target, 'PROP_NAME', inst);

//retrieve the instance
var inst =  $.data(target, 'PROP_NAME');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the example you gave, you only have one type of AJAX request, `POST`ed to the same URL with the same data every time.  If that's the case, you should just need something like :

```
var brokerResponse = null;  // <-- Global variable

function populateSelect(whatWasClicked) {
 var thisSelect = $(whatWasClicked).parents("div").find("select") ;

 if (!brokerResponse) {  // <-- Does an old response exist? If not, get one...
   var before = function() { $(loading).show() ;  } ;
   var complete = function() { $(loading).hide() ;  } ;
   var data = {'_service' : 'myService', '_program' : 'myProgram' } ;
   var error = function(){alert("Error"); } ;

   var success = function(request) {  // <-- Store the response before use
      brokerResponse = request; 
      $(thisSelect).html(brokerResponse);
   };
   var waitTime = 20000 ;

   ajaxCall(thisSelect, waitTime, before, complete, data, success, error ) ;
 }
 else {   // <-- If it already existed, we get here.
   $(thisSelect).html(brokerResponse);  // <-- Use the old response
 }
}
```

If you have multiple possible items for `whatWasClicked` which each need a different AJAX response cached, then you need to have some string with which to identify `whatWasClicked`, and use that to store multiple values in your global variable.  For example, if you have a unique `id` on `whatWasClicked`, this would work:

```
var brokerResponse = {}; // Global variable is a simple object

function populateSelect(whatWasClicked) {

 var whatWasClickedId = $(whatWasClicked).attr('id'); // Get the unique ID
 var thisSelect = $(whatWasClicked).parents("div").find("select") ;

 if (!brokerResponse[whatWasClickedId]) {  // Check that ID for a response
   var before = function() { $(loading).show() ;  } ;
   var complete = function() { $(loading).hide() ;  } ;
   var data = {'_service' : 'myService', '_program' : 'myProgram' } ;
   var error = function(){alert("Error"); } ;
   var success = function(request) {

      brokerResponse[whatWasClickedId] = request; // Using ID
      $(thisSelect).html(brokerResponse);
   };
   var waitTime = 20000 ;

   ajaxCall(thisSelect, waitTime, before, complete, data, success, error ) ;
 }
 else {
   $(thisSelect).html(brokerResponse[whatWasClickedId]); // Etc...
 }
}
```

Comment: The second part of your answer, using the ID of the element to reference the data in a global array, is a good answer. I was hoping that a function, stored in a variable, could be passed along and executed in the ajaxCall function, but I guess that is not how js works.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's scoping is such that if you just declared a global variable, you should be able to access it from within the ajax success function and the click function as well.

```
var _global_holder = null;
$('#getSelectOptions').bind("click", function() {
 if(_global_holder==null) { whatever }
 populateSelect(this);
});

function populateSelect(whatWasClicked) {
 if(_global_holder !== null) {
    whatever
  } else { whatever else }

 ajaxCall(thisSelect, waitTime, before, complete, data, success, error ) ;
}

function ajaxCall(elementToPopulate, waitTime, whatToDoBeforeAjaxSend,
                  whatToDoAfterAjaxSend, dataToSendToTheServer, 
                  whatToDoAfterSuccess, whatToDoAfterError) {
...
}
```